# How can I connect Wi-Fi on Hololens2 with Single App Kiosk Mode enabled

Tags: hololens

I'm developing a commercial mixed reality app with hololens 2. The single app kiosk mode provide straightforward user experience as app will start automatically and no disturbance start menu will show up during operations.

However, with single app kiosk mode, the start menu is disabled, which means the WiFi configuration is not accessible. Besides, according to my research, WiFi connection is not feasible with C# script within application. So how could I enable user to config WiFi under single app kiosk mode.

Many thanks!